# How can I force an embeded PDF to display at "Page Width" zoom level?

Tags: pdf, iframe, embed

I'm using `embed` to embed a pdf into my web page.  I could also use `object` or `iframe`.  I want the pdf to open full width of the page, which i have working.  But I want the zoom level to be "Page Width".  Ive seen several solutions for height, like `#view=FitH` and some for specific percentages, but not "Page Width"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most PDF settings are browser specific and subject to user control so here a Chrome based Edge (on the left) and a Firefox based clone (on the right) the biggest problem noticed in these four types of loading is the lack of object support (totally missing in bottom right). Note:- I have security set so only the high speed secured Firefox based plugin viewer will show me PDFs inline without risk of running a script.

However in direct answer to the question not all browsers support the acrobat#tags but most will attempt #zoom=50% (and #page= except perhaps Safari?) whereas fit has frequently been an odd behaviour difference between all of the camps. I show the chrome result below.

[image]

the correct tag could be #FitW and that's what I used when chrome unsecured viewing is turned on
[image]